# Can't uninstall visual studio 2013 express

Tags: windows-8.1, uninstall, visual-studio-2010

I saw that a community edition of visual studio was released, and as that seems like a better idea then  3 separate installations of visual studio, i tried to uninstall the visual studio 2013 express installations but i only get

> An error occurred while trying to uninstall Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Express 2013 For XXXXX - ENU. It many have already been uninstalled.
>
> Would you like to remove Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 For
>   XXXXX - ENU from the Program and Features list?

I have Update 2 and not 4 so if i download and run the setup package for Visual studio express i only get a setup option.

So is there any program that i can start on my own to start a uninstall.

Comment: You say you have "3 separate installations of visual studio", if so, did you uninstall any of them successfully?  When you say "Yes, go ahead and remove it" in response to the mention prompt, did it remove it from the Add/Remove list? If so, then what's the problem exactly?

Comment: It sounds like VS its uninstalled enough that you can simply install the edition you actually want.

Comment: Uninstall each of the 3 products.  Once you do that just install the `VS 2013 Community Edition`.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 if i press Yes, it simply removes it from the list of program i can uninstall, but the program will still be installed. But no i have only pressed no as i see no logic in pressing yes..

Comment: @Ramhound I can't uninstall the products thats the problem....

Comment: What makes you think it's still installed after doing that?

Comment: They are already uninstalled then

Comment: @Ramhound there must be some magic in my computer as i still can start them with no problem....

Comment: So install them again and uninstall them; because windows thinks they are not installed; your installations are semi-broken

Comment: @Ramhound i tried that yesterday the uninstallation process just hung it self... i guess ill just reinstall the OS instead...